# Would it be okay to remove location property in resource file?

Tags: c#, winforms, designer, resx, tablelayoutpanel

I am working on a windows application with 64 bit C++ and C# components. As you know VS 2015 is still 32 bit, so it does not support application in design mode. I can't see my forms. But I have to make some UI changes. One way of doing this is making changes directly to resX and designer.cs files.

In my case I have an existing text box within TableLayoutPanel. Assume just one text box to simplify but in the project they are many. It has a location property. After relocation of my text box I removed location property for the text box in the resource file and form displays fine if I run the project. Is it okay to remove location property?

I tested in small project and property window still showed location coordinates correctly even it was removed from resx and designer files.

Your advice and help greatly appreciated!

Ahror

Comment: Is there a reason you can't build for 32-bit mode and use the designer that way? Why not separate-out your UI/designer components into a separate project if you have 32-bit incompatible components?

Comment: The reason is project and project references are 64 bit. I can change references and project itself to 32 bit but it requires me to reinstall whole system. It is kind of long way. Separating a peace to different project is difficult because I am dealing with too many controls. But good news is it is working now. The project was not synced completely with referencing components. That's why it was giving me a UI related issues. Thanks for your response anyway. I appreciate it.